# JSX formatting in WebStorm - indentation

Tags: webstorm

Consider this JSX expression:

```
return <><p>Some text</p><p><strong>Some more text!</strong></p></>;
```

Currently, upon pressing `Ctrl+Alt+L` WebStorm says it's already properly formatted.

Please tell me how to introduce automatic indentation of every tag based on nesting, as shown here:

```
return <>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>
        <strong>Some more text!</strong>
    </p>
</>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX formatting is configured in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**; please try removing `p` from **Don't break if inline content** and `strong` - from **Inline elements** list on **Other** tab